# Replacing word in position X of a string C++

Tags: c++, string, function

I am trying to write a function in a program that will take a string, a word and an integer and use the int as the index value and the word as the replacement value. For example, if the string is "This is a test.", the word is "example", and the number is 4, then the result would be "This is an example". This is what I have so far (I had to make multiple copies of the string because eventually, I am going to be passing it into two other functions by reference instead of as value)Right now it is using the character index instead of the word index in order to replace. How do I fix that?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string Input = "";
string Word = "";
int Number = 0;

cout << "Pleas enter a string using only lower case letters. \n";
getline(cin, Input);

cout << "Please enter a word using only lower case lettersS. \n";
getline(cin, Word);

cout << "Please enter a number. \n";
cin >> Number;

string StringCopy1 = Input;
string StringCopy2 = Input;
string StringCopy3 = Input;
 }

 void stringFunctionValue(string StringCopy1, int Number, string Word) 
{
  StringCopy1.replace(Number, Word.length, Word);
  return StringCopy1;
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Provide the problem description.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please consider rephrasing your question, since as such what you want is unclear, and does not allow member to help you correctly.

Comment: If, for example string "stringcopy1" is "Like like apples" and string "Word" is "oranges" and int "Number" is 3 I need "stringFunctionValue to identify the 3rd word in the string and replace it with oranges. The result would be "I like oranges". It essentially needs to identify the word in the "int number" space in the string, and then replace that word with the given "word" value.

Comment: What you have tried so far to achieve it? your stringFunctionValue() function is empty.

Comment: I have tried a few things and nothing has worked. I'm asking how to write the function.

Comment: Show what you have tried. You might be off by some fiddly little bit.

Comment: @Ryan I will suggest you to read about std::string functions, you will find a function by name 'replace'. Try using it and let us know you are able to achieve the result. It is not good to ask directly the solution of the problem without trying it, its about learning from the mistakes and grow.

Comment: So if i use string String.replace(Number, Word.length, Word); It replaces the character index instead of the word index. How do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is find the nth word.

The first thing to come to mind is using [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to pull the string apart with `>>` and a [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to write the new string.

```
std::istringstream in(StringCopy1);
std::string token;
std::ostringstream out;
int count = 0;
while (in >> token) // while we can get more tokens
{
    if (++count != number) // not the number of the token to replace
    {
        out << token << " "; // write the token
    }
    else
    {
        out << word << " "; // write the replacement word
    }
}
return out.str();
```

While this is easy to write, it has two problems: It loses the correct type of whitespace in the `string` AND places an extra space on the end of the string. It's also kind of slow and uses a lot more memory than if you modify the string in place.

Use [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) to find the first non-whitespace character. This will be the start of the first word. Then use [`std::string::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to find the next whitespace character. This will be the end of the word. Alternate back and forth finding non-whitespace then whitespace until you find the beginning and ending of the nth word. `std::string::replace` that word. This approach requires you to write more and more complicated code, but is much more satisfying. This is why I outlined it rather than fully implementing it: To allow you the joy for yourself.

Note: `void stringFunctionValue(string StringCopy1, int Number, string Word)` gives you no way to provide the result back to the user. This makes for an unhelpful function. Consider returning a `string` rather than `void`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I do want to try doing it a bit more manually but for now this solution works great. That you for taking the time to respond.